# Is it normal to have 500k Amazon Route 53 DNS-Queries in 5 days?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

Hi I'm hosting very simple server on aws eb and i use route 53 to have https on it. I have set it up recently and in this month (in 5 days) I already have to pay 0.50$ for DNS-Queries. I know it aint much but i dont want to pay 3$ a month for a server that no one almost uses

Comment: Are you seeing a $.50 charge for Route53 in general, or a $.50 charge for just the DNS queries?

Comment: https://imgur.com/3NT2h1o idk if im reading it correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you are seeing the $.50/month charge for a hosted zone. 500K DNS queries would not cost that much. According to the [Route53 Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/pricing/) the cost for DNS queries is $0.40 per million queries – first 1 Billion queries / month

Comment: check this out,  maybe im not reading it correctly https://imgur.com/3NT2h1o

Comment: It's what I thought it was. You are seeing a charge for the hosted zone (configuration for a domain). Each one is $.50/month.

Comment: Also note that the picture indicates that you had 503 queries, not 503,000 queries. The three zeroes after the decimal point is a bit confusing.